# Problems with compiling more then one sketch in the Arduino IDE

Tags: esp8266, avrdude, compiler

I found this [ESP8266-MQTT program on Github.](https://github.com/rkubera/ESP8266-MQTT-to-Serial-Bridge)

How can I compile this thing with the Arduino IDE?

I only can open one sketch at a time. If I try to compile this then parts of the program are missing for AVRDUDE - but they are in the same folder.

Please can you help me?

Comment: Looks like it is all one sketch, though there are multiple .ino files... but the project folder name has to be exactly "ESP8266-MQTT-to-Serial-Bridge", that tells the Arduino IDE that the main project file is named "ESP8266-MQTT-to-Serial-Bridge.ino". The other files contain additional supporting code and must be in the same folder.

Comment: thanks but it did not work :(      I have tried both ways.

Comment: I can open it in Arduino IDE 1.8.13, but can't build on my system due to missing library (`ESP8266WiFi.h: No such file or directory`). Not really a avrdude issue. Can you update your question to show exactly what error messages you get (Sketch | Verify/Compile, then "Copy error messages")

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I get messages that parts are missing. You must make from ESP8266WiFi.h to WiFI.h I have a ESP32 and i am using Ubuntu.

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/35117/fatal-error-esp8266wifi-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/48669/includeesp8266wifi-h-showing-error-message

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/58751/7174

Comment: thanks but this are not liberys. This are parts of the sketch.

Comment: Related: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/71405/whats-the-relation-between-arduino-standard-library-and-esp8266-library

Comment: thanks but i have no libery proplem!!!

Comment: "I have a ESP32" and... "ESP8266-MQTT-to-Serial-Bridge" ... see the problem?

Comment: ok thanks  But normaly i can use a sketch for both.

Comment: I could compile the program fine, when I removed all lines with `#include <String.h>` (I don't know, why this is included, since the `String` class in Arduino is available without including something). Just open the `ESP8266-MQTT-to-Serial-Bridge`, then the Arduino IDE will open with that sketch and the other files (cpp, h, ino) will be in the same window in different tabs.

Comment: Though I compiled for the ESP8266. You cannot compile that for the ESP32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sketch is written for the ESP8266, not the ESP32. The two are very different chips, and the libraries used are very different.

You will have to learn how the sketch works, and how the ESP32 libraries work, and port the sketch to the ESP32 once you have learned how.

Comment: thanks Is there some sketch for the ESP32 ?

Comment: There are plenty of sketches for the ESP32. One that does that exact same thing? Dunno. Ask Google.